# Render vector tiles with text label in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, labeling, vector-tiles

I’m trying to leaflet to render about 30K points with their names. The text label should avoid overlapping, and important points should always be rendered firstly.

My strategy is:

1. Use tippecanoe to make mbtiles file from geojson. (To make sure important points be rendered firstly, I have specified tippecanoe's minzoom and maxzoom for each point. )
2. Use tileserver-gl to serve vector tile.
3. Use VectorGrid plugin to render the vector tiles in leaflet.

I trying to use maputnik to make a style.json file, which seems very nice dealing with text label overlapping. However, I sadly find out leaflet VectorGrid plugin does not support style.json file.
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/issues/196

Now I'm stuck. What is my alternative to rendering those points with names?

Comment: Whats wrong with vector grid styling: https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.VectorGrid/vectorgrid-api-docs.html#styling-vectorgrids?

Comment: Have a look also at  [Leaflet.VectorTileLayer](https://gitlab.com/jkuebart/Leaflet.VectorTileLayer/) plugin, which is built on top of Leaflet.VectorGrid.

Comment: @TomazicM. I couldn't find out how to add textual properties in VectorGrids styling.   https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/issues/67

Comment: Ah, now I understand. I once tried to deal with the same problem. Found a bit hacked solution that worked for my needs. It's based on the idea to create text part of features as tooltips dynamically only for the visible features. You can have a look at working JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/2o9z53u6/. Here 15.000 random points are created and tooltips showed only for zoom levels over 10. Display logic can of course be adjusted to reflect some feature properties. You might get some idea from this.

Comment: @TomazicM Thank you very much for the inspiration.  
I came out with a workaround using getFeatureId option of vectorGrid.
https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.VectorGrid/vectorgrid-api-docs.html#updating-styles. 
For each point, I make it into divIcon with their text properties,  then add it to collisionLayer to avoid overlapping.
https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision 
Very clumsy, but doable.

Comment: Good idea! I had something similar in mind with style function, but problem there would be that feature object with coordinates is not available in style function, so point coordinate would have to be one of the properties of the point feature.

Comment: @TomazicM yes, I forgot to mention that. I had to add coordinates as properties for each point, and also set the style to transparent for the default rendering by VectorGrid. Fell very clumsy.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution. You could publish it as and answer to your own question (with some code of course), so somebody with similar problems/requirements can benefit from it.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the inspiration from @TomazicM, I came up with this workaround with getFeatureId option of vectorGrid and leaflet layerGroup.collision plugin.

Firstly, add coordinates as properties for each point before making mbtiles file.

For each point render by tileserver-gl, using getFeatureId to get each point's coordinates and name properties, then make it to divIcon. Add each divIcon as marker to collisionLayer to avoid overlapping.
[github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision](https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision)

Finally, set style to transparent for the default rendering by VectorGrid.

My code is something like this, very clumsy, but doable. Please let me you if you have other solution.

```
 const vectorTileOptions = {
  getFeatureId: function (e) {
    const latlngs = [e.properties.lat, e.properties.lng];
    const stationName = e.properties.name;
    const marker = L.marker(latlngs, {
      icon: L.divIcon({
        html: `<img src=${redpointIcon} height="10" width="10" ><span class=labelName>${stationName}</span>`,
        iconAnchor: [5, 10],
      }),
    });
    collisionLayer.addLayer(marker);
  },
  vectorTileLayerStyles: {
    point: { color: "transparent" },
  },
};
L.vectorGrid.protobuf("http://[::]:8080/data/point/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf", vectorTileOptions).addTo(map);
collisionLayer.addTo(map);
```